# TypeScript: Inheritance from child to parent with inteface

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Is it possible to get properties from child interface to the parent ?

exemple:

```
interface A {
title: string;
id: string;
}

interface B extends A {
author: string;
}

const book: A = {
title: 'my title',
id: '1',
// author is from interface B
author: 'author'
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to get properties of subtype interface having only super type. Please provide an example of how you use it in your original code

Comment: Please [edit] the example code here so that it demonstrates why you can't just annotate `book` as `B` instead of `A` (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w11rOw) and like in @Pilpo's answer), or why you can't just leave off the annotation entirely like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK8jgw).

Answer (score 0):

`book` has to be of type `B` if you want it to have the `author` attribute

```
const book :B = { // <-- it's B not A
  title: 'test',
  id: 'idTest',
  author: 'authorTest' // <-- obtains this attribute from interface B
}
console.log(book);
```

Output

```
{
  "title": "test",
  "id": "idTest",
  "author": "authorTest"
}
```

You can't have properties of `B` inside an object of type `A` because inheritance only work from top to bottom.

Comment: yes the example was to be simple. In my project, I need to use interface A by using properties in interface B
I really need to retrieve properties in a child interface to use in a variable with type Parent Interface

Comment: Inheritance doesn't work the way up, it's only top to bottom.

Comment: @Younes please demonstrate why this suggestion doesn't work, by providing a [mre] of a use case where it fails.  As stated, your question is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), where you have some underlying use case X, but the thing you're asking for Y is not possible.  If you could show some example of X, then maybe someone can suggest another solution, like using type guards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you extend your interface `A` a bit with `[prop: string]: unknown;`, like this

```
interface A {
  title: string;
  id: string;
  [prop: string]: unknown;
}

interface B extends A {
  author: string;
}

const book: A = {
  title: 'my title',
  id: '1',
  // author is from interface B
  author: 'author',
};
```

then it will compile. However it a little bit defeats the purpose of types in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) as it will let you have the properties from the parent and child interface.

```
interface A {
  title: string;
  id: string;
}

interface B extends A {
  author: string;
}

const book: A | B = {
  title: "my title",
  id: "1",
  // author is from interface B
  author: "author",
};
```